# Java Sigma Equation Solving sigma(i=1 to k)((-1)^i+1)(i)(i+1) Timedout for long values

Tags: java, induction

> Getting timedout error while calculating the value of sigma notation 
>   sigma(i=1 to k)((-1)^i+1)(i)(i+1) for very long values example :10^8 
>   .Can any one guide me where I am doing wrong

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
        for(int t_i=0; t_i<T; t_i++)
        {
            int params1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());

            long out_ = maxValueX(params1);
            System.out.println(out_);
            System.out.println("");
         }

         wr.close();
         br.close();
    }
    static long maxValueX(long params1){
        long sum=0;
       for(long i=1;i<=params1;i++){
           sum=(long)Math.pow(-1,i+1)*i*(i+1)+sum;
       }
       return sum;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to simplify that sigma expression. If `params1` is even:

```
1*2 - 2*3 + 3*4 - 4*5 + 5*6 - 6*7 + ... =
(1*2 - 2*3) + (3*4 - 4*5) + (5*6 - 6*7) + ... =
2*(1-3) + 4*(3-5) + 6*(5-7) + ... =
-2*2 + -2*4 + -2*6 + ... =
-2*2*(1 + 2 + 3 + ...)
```

Now, there is a closed-form formula for the parenthesized term, so you don't even need to compute it iteratively: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

This approach also works for an odd `params1`, except that there'll be an extra term at the end that needs to be accounted for.

With some further algebraic manipulations (left as an exercise for the reader), one can derive a single formula that works for both odd and even arguments. In pseudo-code (that happens to be valid Python):

```python
def linear_time(n):
  return sum((-1)**(i+1)*i*(i+1) for i in range(1, n+1))

def constant_time(n):
  return (-1)**n * (-n*n//2 - n)

for n in (100, 101, 120, 100000, 1297981):
  print linear_time(n), constant_time(n)
```

(That exponentiation is just a lazy shortcut for computing the sign; we don't actually need to compute the exponent for that.)

Comment: Thank You :-) Will give a try Nice Approach

Comment: I had another small Query If i need to find maximum sum in the simga expansion should I must calculate every possible value.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question. I'd suggest that you post it in a separate question, with enough detail to make it clear what's being asked.